# How does the in operator work with sets in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, set

Why does the following code:

`'%' in new Set('%');`

return false?

And is the in operator faster on a set than on an array?

Comment: It works the same way as with arrays: it doesn't.

Comment: What part of [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) gave you the idea that `in` can be used with sets?

Comment: The documentation doesn't specify anything of the sort, but it might be because of [the in operator in python](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/in-and-not-in-operators-in-python) that behaves similarly as `Set.prototype.has` and `Array.prototype.includes` in javascript

Answer (score 5):

The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.

It does not check if something belongs to a set. You should use [Set.prototype.has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) for that.

```js
const obj = { someKey: 'someValue' };
'someKey' in obj; // true
'someOtherKey' in obj; // false

const set = new Set([1,2,3]);
set.has(1); // true
set.has(4); // false
```

Regarding performance, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55639858/8186898)